# htacess url rewrites for .php?=n

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking to rewrite old PHP pages to new locations, however the previous system used URLs structured as follows:

```
/old-page.php?page=Our%20Services
```

I've tried the following:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.php?page=Our%20Services http://www.newdomain.co.uk/our-services/
```

Can someone help explain to me why the rewrite rule ignores everything after the question mark please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) for simple cases only. If you want to check the query string, you must use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=Our%20Services
RewriteRule ^old-page.php$ http://www.newdomain.co.uk/our-services/ [R,L]
```

This checks, if the query string contains `page=Our%20Services` and the URL path is `old-page.php`. It then redirects the client to the new URL `http://www.newdomain.co.uk/our-services/`.